# Why won't my symmetry align correctly on my sculpt?

Tags: sculpting, mirror

I'm sculpting a finger, however tje Y symmetry seems to be compltely offset. I've applied all transforms and the origin is roughly in the centre of the object. Why would it be doing this? [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share the object so that we can check (remove the useless parts)?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the Armature Deform :

[image]

---

While sculpting you can (temporary) disable it here :

[image]